# What Is the Regex Patten for only special characters not digits and alphabets (Using fluent validation with .Matches())?)

Tags: .net, c#-5.0, fluentvalidation

For Example:

```
Rule(x=x.Password)
    .Matches(@"(**?:[^​˜!@#$]*[˜​!@#$]**){" + count+ "}")
    .WithMessage("Password should contain at least {0} special character(s)", count);
```

Here in above not matches all special characters like dot,plus+ etc.

Answer (score 6):

Declare regex variable like below line.

```
readonly Regex regEx = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
```

Refer below code for usage.

```
RuleFor(x=x.Password).Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
             .Matches(regEx)
             .WithMessage("Password should contain at least {0} special character(s)", "Password"));
```

Comment: Can you please provide regex that not accepts [a-zA-Z0-9] with count {5},{6} etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use a single regex to do this. But you can use [custom validator](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/e.-Custom-Validators) for your validation.

```
class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{

    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.Name).SetValidator(new PasswordValidator());
    }
}

class PasswordValidator : PropertyValidator
{
    private const int Count = 3;
    private readonly Regex regex;
    const string expression = @"[^A-Za-z0-9]";

    public PasswordValidator()
        : base(() => "Property {PropertyName} is not in the correct format.")
    {
        regex = new Regex(expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        if (context.PropertyValue == null) return false;
        var collection = regex.Matches((string)context.PropertyValue);
        return collection.Count >= Count;
    }
}
```